# Add custom field to logstash

Tags: python, ruby, twitter, elasticsearch, logstash

I am using the Twitter input and the Elasticsearch output to Logstash. In logstash I want to analyze the incoming tweet and add a new field based on some algorithm. I understand that I'd need to write a new plugin but the examples I've come across are all in Ruby.

Is it possible to write the plugin in Python? If not, please share any good tutorials on how to write one in Ruby.

Comment: Plugins can't be written in Python. Are you aware of the [Extending Logstash](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/extending/) part of the documentation and the specific example of [adding a new filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/extending/example-add-a-new-filter)?

Comment: I did have a look at both of those but I am not proficient in Ruby so wanted to ask if there was any way to do this in Python.

Answer (score 3):

I personal would not use the ruby code, but use the mutate plugin (http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate)

For the configuration you can also use the provided conditionals. Examples can be found here: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/configuration#conditionals

```
if [type] == 'tweet' {
    mutate {
        add_field => { "newfield" => "value can contain variables from the entire message" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you'd suggest against using the Ruby plugin? (Sorry for coming back to this after a couple of months)

Comment: If it's already available as module, why should you use the core ruby version? There might not be a speed difference (don't know), but trusting the functions is higher as code. Modules also have sanity checks.

Comment: Thanks @volker. I tried using mutate but it didn't work :( I've put up [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916814/add-fields-to-logstash-twitter-input-and-elasticsearch-output).

Answer (score 2):

If your algorithm is not complicated, you can use [Ruby](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/ruby) filter plugin to do your requirement.

For example,

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
            if event['type'] == 'tweet' 
                event['newfield'] = 'Come from Twitter'
            end 
        "
    }
}
```

This will add a field with name `newfield` and the value is `Come from Twitter`

Comment: Very cool. My algo wouldn't be complicated. Is there a limit as to how big/complicated this Ruby code in quotes can be?

Comment: Also, what is this `add_field` I keep seeing in all filters?

Comment: Any algo can run in the ruby code if you can implement it in ruby. lol. It's not hard to learn ruby. You can try to implement your own algo. Beside, the  new field added can see in the following filter below the ruby filter. So, It you want the new_field can be see, you can put the ruby plugin to be the first filter.